# Can only start Pycharm manually calling pycharm.sh

Tags: python, pycharm

I don't know why but every time I try to start PyCharm after having go to Tools->Create Desktop Entry I get the following

[image]

Now, as I saw in some similar questions, I've added both JAVA_HOME and PYCHARM_JDK to my .zshrc file (I use oh-my-zsh)

```
# This is for Pycharm
export JAVA_HOME="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
export JDK_HOME="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
export PYCHARM_JDK="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
```

By the way if you're wondering what .sdkman is, I use it to handle different Java versions, if you check what it points to, it's a valid Java installation

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -ltra /home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java
total 16
lrwxrwxrwx 1 internetmosquito internetmosquito   11 feb 10 20:24 current -> 11.0.2-open
drwxr-xr-x 9 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 8u152-zulu
drwxr-xr-x 4 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 11.0.2-open
drwxr-xr-x 5 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 ..
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  ls -ltra /home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/11.0.2-open 
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  4 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 include
drwxr-xr-x  2 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 bin
drwxr-xr-x  6 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 internetmosquito internetmosquito 1214 feb 10 20:24 release
drwxr-xr-x  2 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 jmods
drwxr-xr-x 72 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 legal
drwxr-xr-x  8 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 internetmosquito internetmosquito 4096 feb 10 20:24 conf
```

So if I try to echo any of those variables Pycharm is looking for, I get legit output...

```
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  echo $JDK_HOME
/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
 internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~  echo $PYCHARM_JDK
/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current
```

And obviously, java works fine

```
 ✘ internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~/Downloads/pycharm-2019.1/bin  java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)
```

Funny thing is that if I run pycharm.sh manually in terminal, everything works fine...

```
internetmosquito@internetmosquito-PE72-7RD  ~/Downloads/pycharm-2019.1/bin  ./pycharm.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to field sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-02-14 21:47:41,590 [   1332]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Markdown support" is incompatible (until build 173.SNAPSHOT < PY-193.7288.30) 
2021-02-14 21:47:41,986 [   1728]   WARN - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin "Markdown support" is incompatible (until build 173.SNAPSHOT < PY-193.7288.30) 
2021-02-14 21:47:42,469 [   2211]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - List.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2021-02-14 21:47:42,473 [   2215]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Table.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2021-02-14 21:47:42,473 [   2215]   WARN - com.intellij.ide.ui.LafManager - Tree.rowHeight = 0 in Darcula; it may lead to performance degradation 
2021-02-14 21:47:42,535 [   2277]   WARN - s.impl.EditorColorsManagerImpl - Cannot find scheme: VibrantInk from plugins: com.intellij.database
```

So...my take is that whenever I run this from a desktop entry, it simply doesn't get my env variables for some reason? Any pointers? Not sure if this is related with sdkman, but I had this working in the past coexisting with it without issues.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Tools->Create Desktop Entry`, but I don't find it that surprising that your `.zshrc` file isn't sourced into the shell used to launch PyCharm via something built by the app itself.  It could be that `zsh` isn't even used in this case.

Comment: @CryptoFool Hmmm, might that be using bash? I might try to add those variables in .bashrc and see what happens...the weird thing is that I got this working in the past without issues, I just format and installed Ubuntu 20.04 like 2 days ago and was settings thing up...but pretty much my tooling is the same as previous

Comment: You might want to try putting the defs in your `.bash_profile`, or the `zsh` equivalent.  Those files are lower-level than then `.rc` equivalents, and may be used in more situations.

Comment: @CryptoFool I already added this to my zshrc file as you can see in the orignal post

Comment: I understood that.  What I was suggesting is that if `zsh` has an equivalent to `bash`'s `.bash_profile` file (like `.zsh_profile` maybe?), you try putting your definitions in that file instead of `.zshrc`.

Comment: @CryptoFool nope, it doesn't....there's only .zshrc and .zshhistory, I tried adding a variable in .profile to see if that was read by zsh but it doesn't look like it, if I echo it I see nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several options, I added

```
export JAVA_HOME="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
export JDK_HOME="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
export PYCHARM_JDK="/home/internetmosquito/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"
```

to /etc/environment and it eventually worked. I will improve this a bit because basically means that if I uninstall sdkman I won't be able to start again but for now suffices